# Terraform for_each azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group dynamic rule

Tags: azure, terraform

I have terraform file **nonfunctionalvms.tf** that creates multiple VMs

```
module "nonfunctional" {
  source         = "../../modules/additionalvms"
  resource_group = var.resource_group
  vmname        = "nf-add-vm"
  instances = {
    TICKET-F2345 = { name = "F2345" }
    TICKET-F2471 = { name = "F2371" }   
  }
}
```

Creating VMs, OS disks, NIC, and configuring OS - all works fine.
Inside that module I need to (trying to) dynamically allow http/s access. I am trying to create dynamic section under firewall policy with no success.

Content of **modules/additionalvms/firewall_policy.tf** file:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "policy-additionalvms" {
  name               = "policy-additionalvms"
  firewall_policy_id = data.azurerm_firewall_policy.nonfunctional.id
  priority           = 2300
  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "policy-additionalvms"
    priority = 2312
    action   = "Allow"
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = var.instances
      content {
        name = allow-web-out[each.key]
        protocols {
          type = "Http"
          port = 80
        }
        protocols {
          type = "Https"
          port = 443
        }
        source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvms[each.key].private_ip_address]
        destination_fqdns = ["*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to add only additional IPs of VMs to existing rule collection
Where am i wrong? The is the error I am getting:

```
│ Error: Invalid reference
│   on ../../modules/jenkins/firewall_policy.tf line 12, in resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "Policy-additionalvms":
│   12:       name = allow-web-out[each.key]
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
│ Error: Reference to "each" in context without for_each
│   on ../../modules/jenkins/firewall_policy.tf line 12, in resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "Policy-additionalvms":
│   12:       name = allow-web-out[each.key]
│ The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.
│ Error: Reference to "each" in context without for_each
│   on ../../modules/jenkins/firewall_policy.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "Policy-additionalvms":
│   21:       source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvms-nic[each.key].private_ip_address]
│ The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.
```

Comment: Added **content** section

Comment: It should be `rule.key` probably: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks. Search for `iterator`.

Comment: ***** what a mistake. You are correct correct solution is: **name = "allow-web-out-${rule.key}"** also **source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvm-nic[rule.key].private_ip_address]**. Thank you for pointing my error.

Comment: No worries, always happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
module "nonfunctional" {
  source         = "../../modules/additionalvms"
  resource_group = var.resource_group
  vmname        = "nf-add-vm"
  instances = {
    TICKET-F2345 = { name = "F2345" }
    TICKET-F2471 = { name = "F2371" }   
  }
}
```

And the firewall policy is:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "policy-additionalvms" {
  name               = "policy-additionalvms"
  firewall_policy_id = data.azurerm_firewall_policy.nonfunctional.id
  priority           = 2300
  application_rule_collection {
    name     = "policy-additionalvms"
    priority = 2312
    action   = "Allow"
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = var.instances
      content {
        name = "allow-web-out-${rule.key}"
        protocols {
          type = "Http"
          port = 80
        }
        protocols {
          type = "Https"
          port = 443
        }
        source_addresses  = [azurerm_network_interface.additionalvms[rule.key].private_ip_address]
        destination_fqdns = ["*"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```